# Crontab not found in docker image

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I have a docker image set up by another person, and it doesn't seem to have cron installed. When I tried to run `crontab -l` (be it as a root or non-root user), it says `command not found`. But I do see `/etc/cron.d` with a single file in the folder: `e2scrub_all`.

I'm confused - does this docker image have cron or not? If it does, how do I run a cronjob?

Comment: Either it isn't installed..  or   it's installed in a non-standard path.  You'll need to search your paths for crontab.

Comment: Have you check if the `cron` package is installed?

Comment: I did a `which cron`, but there was no result. Does that mean cron is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the cron files have nothing related to cron/tab. If the periodical job is critical to a program (`e2scrub` in your case), its package should depend on cron. So if you want e2scrub to run periodically, it'd be better to explicitly add cron to the docker image.

Anyway you can ensure it by finding which package `/etc/cron.d/e2scrub_all` belongs to with your package manager. That's distribution dependent so I can't give you a direct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I run one of my cron containers.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

ADD crontab.txt /crontab.txt

ADD script.sh /script.sh

COPY entry.sh /entry.sh

RUN chmod 755 /script.sh /entry.sh

RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt

CMD ["/entry.sh"]
```

crontab.txt

```
*/30 * * * * /script.sh >> /var/log/script.log
```

entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# code goes here.
echo "This is a script, run by cron!"
```

Build like so

```
docker build -t mycron .
```

Run like so

```
docker run -d mycron
```

Add your own scripts and edit the

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal that there is no cron in a Docker container. Except when you want a container for cron.

By principle you have only a single service in a container, along with its dependencies.

If you need cron, start another container for it.